# Stop sending requests multiple times due to timeout

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I wrote a lambda function in Py 3.8 which goes something like this:

```
...
       if ext == 'pdf' or ext == 'PDF':
            resp = requests.get("http://...")
            return "Done"
```

Problem is `requests.get` takes more than 3 secs to respond, as a result, the function times out and `requests.get` is called again. How do I stop it from being called multiple times?

I don't mind the timeout, but I don't want it to get called again and again.
Also: I can modify the API  function which is being called if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lambda Console, under Function configuration, you can modify the Retry attempts.

However, one of the core tenets of lambda is keep it stateless. Keeping functions stateless enables AWS Lambda to rapidly launch as many copies of the function as needed to scale to the rate of incoming events.

[image]